# How to configure Tcl on Linux From Scratch?

Tags: compiling, lfs

I got this error following [LFS 6.8, chapter 5, Tcl-8.5.10](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.8/chapter05/tcl.html) to install Tcl:

```
lfs@sam:/mnt/lfs/sources/tcl8.5.9/tools$ ./configure --prefix=/tools
./configure: line 1208: cd: ../../tcl8.5/unix: No such file or directory
configure: error: There's no tclConfig.sh in /mnt/lfs/sources/tcl8.5.9/tools;  perhaps you didn't specify the Tcl *build* directory (not the toplevel Tcl directory) or you forgot to configure Tcl?
lfs@sam:/mnt/lfs/sources/tcl8.5.9/tools$
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc you link, you should be in the `unix` subdirectory of `tcl8.5.9` to run the configure script, not in the `tools` subdirectory.